# visual assist inserts extra spaces?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-assist

I'm using Visual Assist X trial on VS2010 Pro.

When I do extract method or modify method signature refactorings it gives me this:

```
void Solver::Work( Stack &s, Board &b )
```

However I would really appreciate if it gave me this:

```
void Solver::Work(Stack &s, Board &b)
```

No extra spaces. Is there a way to set this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spacing is defined in the VA Snippets whose titles start with "Refactor" - see "Editing VA Snippets" in the VA [documentation](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/vasnippets.asp).  Similar questions have been raised on the Whole Tomato support forum [here](http://www.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=8127) and [here](http://www.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=8061).